# Problems updating packages

Tags: update, aptitude

I am using a RasPi 2 running the latest version of Raspbian (as of 12/5/2016).

`uname -a` produces this:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.11-v7+ #888 SMP Mon May 23 20:10:33 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Here is the error message produced by the command below:

```
$ aptitude update; aptitude upgrade

... 
...
...
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package `psmisc' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 1):

prolly you hit a bug.
to avoid such situations its a good idea to use **apt-listbugs**

apt-get install apt-listbugs

apt gonna tell you when a package is buggy and you may want to pine it with "p"

have fun.